# Is there any way to change lsa format?

Tags: android, image, mobile, restore, xiaomi

I uninstalled miui gallery updates (xiaomi mobile).All of my private pictures have been removed now. I found them in file manager in miui folder , But in LSA format, I want to restore my pictures. Is there any way? Anyone can help me??Is there any way to change lsa format?

I tried to change the file format but it didn't work, I couldn't open the file.